# Trigger function on output from php exec()

Tags: php, console, command-line-interface

I have a video encoding task that is quite time consuming and i run it from php using exec() function. During encoding, software updates console line with percentage done. Is there any way to grab this data in php for later processing, or call php function as data in console is updated.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shell_exec` instead, but that will mean your PHP script will wait for the operation to complete. If you want your users to upload a video, you may not want to make them wait that long. In that case, what you could do is have the user-facing script make an `exec` call to `php processvideo.php` or whatever your heavy script is called, and then use `shell_exec` from there, so you can get the return data.